# "Remember" last three MySql queries; Cookie, passed variable or other method?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, mysql, html

I have a classified website, with pretty sophisticated searching, and I am about to implement a function where the last three queries is displayed for the user, so that the user can go back easier through the queries.
This because for each query the user has to provide a lot of input.

I have four questions for you:

1. I wonder, how can I save the actual query (SELECT * FROM etc etc)...?
2. Do I need to add some form of encryption to be on the safe side?
3. How will this affect performance? (I don't like the fact that cookies slow websites down)
4. Anything else to think about?

If you need more input, let me know...

Btw, the website is PHP based.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser already has a feature called history. When the user clicks the "back" button, the browser will load the previous page. You should rely on this functionality, rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: True that, but as I said, alot of input for each search, so if the user tunes his search along the way, then he has to hit back 10 times to get to where he wants... Better to provide a "wheel" of my own for each major search change etc...

Comment: +1 Damn, why didn't I think of that :) No need to rebuild an existing feature (unless, of course, there are other reasons - and I don't consider performance a reason, almost all browsers can jump back multiple pages at once).

Answer (score 0):

You basically want an undo feature with 3 levels. I would recommend storing each query you execute in an array and reducing that array's size to three afterwards. Very basic implementation (to further explain the idea, this is in no way debugged or feature-complete):

```
function query(&$queue, $mysqli, $sql) {
    if (isset($queue[2])) {
        $queue[0] = $queue[1];
        $queue[1] = $queue[2];
        unset($queue[2]);
    }
    $queue[] = $sql;
    return $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

You can use the queue to display the queries to the user or jump back (don't forget to update the queue if you do that) or whatever else you need.

I wouldn't send the queries via cookies, but rather store them in the session and display them to the user if he needs it - otherwise he will send you arbitrary sql statements - like `INSERT INTO user (username, password, isadmin) VALUES (...` - with his $_COOKIEs (users can forge cookies - *very* easily).

Btw: *never* think about performance in PHP until you're finished - it is so much easier to optimize clean code to bug-fix optimized code. Implement first, measure later. If this turns out to be a bottleneck, start thinking about optimizations.

Comment: If by passing along you mean storing it in the session to have it ready in consecutive http requests, yes.

Comment: bad advice on the last line. You do not want to waste time implementing something that will turn out to be inefficient. Think of a suitable solution with performance in mind and implement it, that should be the last line.

Comment: @Abs: In my experience, PHP developers try to start optimizing from day one. That's why I think it is much better advise to not optimize at all (instead of encouraging performance-based thinking in a language that was designed for ease of use).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't save the actual queries - what if the user managed to edit one?

Either save the url of the 3 previous results page (assuming you're validating your input variables, this should be safer) or save the query in the database with a unique key, then use the key as reference rather than the query.